# Entity Framework error : "Navigation properties can only participate in a single relationship"

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

I am having setup similar to below

```
public class Component
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public List<ComponentUpdate> Updates { get; set; }
    public ComponentUpdate LastUpdate { get; set; }
}

public class ComponentUpdate
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public Component Component { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

and I have setup like

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Component>().HasMany(c => c.Updates).WithOne(u => u.Component);
modelBuilder.Entity<ComponentUpdate>().HasOne(u => u.Component).WithOne(c => c.LastUpdate);
```

But Entity Framework is throwing an error:

> Navigation properties can only participate in a single relationship

What is the problem with above setup? I want to fetch last update at times using navigational property. It seems like an EF limitation...

Answer (score 2):

You must define a separate navigation property for each relationship and you must also define a foreign key for the second relationship:

```
   public class Component
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public List<ComponentUpdate> Updates { get; set; }
        public ComponentUpdate LastUpdate { get; set; }
    }


    public class ComponentUpdate
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
        public Component Component { get; set; }
        public int SecondComponentId { get; set; }
        public Component SecondComponent { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
    
     builder.Entity<Component>()
        .HasMany(c => c.Updates)
        .WithOne(u => u.Component);

     builder.Entity<ComponentUpdate>()
        .HasOne(u => u.SecondComponent)
        .WithOne(c => c.LastUpdate)
        .HasForeignKey<ComponentUpdate>(x => x.SecondComponentId);
```

Comment: but then that would result in another property with exact same information, so its duplication of data just to get around EF limitation

Comment: If they are always same, there is no need for a one-one relationship.you can remove ` public ComponentUpdate LastUpdate { get; set; }` from componet class.

Comment: But then I want to use that navigational property to get info about `latest update`

Comment: Last item in  `Updates` list is your latest update and no need add navigation property for it .

Comment: which means, if I have 100 updates, I should get all of them to get only one time... thats a problem

Comment: performance isn't subject of this question,but one solution is this: `var result = 
from c in _db.Components
select new {component=c,lastUpdate= c.Updates.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault() }.ToList();`